# how to use confirm in jalert plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

does anyone know how to use `jalert`  confirm plugin  here is documentation: http://flwebsites.biz/jAlert/

why i want to use that, i don't want to `prevent` multiple pop, which is default behaviour of chrome

```js
var name = prompt('please enter your name');


alert(name);
```

i'm not getting any clear picture how to use it!!

Comment: it didn't help you for how to setup https://github.com/VersatilityWerks/jAlert

Comment: @bharadwajaGummadi, for `confirm` they have given this code `confirm(function(){
    console.log('confirmed!');
  }, function(){
    console.log('denied');
  });`

Comment: i don't know how to use that

Comment: hope it might help you,  https://github.com/VersatilityWerks/jAlert/issues/5 , for me it worked.

Comment: question is how to implement it, can you create jsfiddle if you don't mind

Comment: I did not found any prompt style feature in your given plugin.

Comment: @Hanif, the above prompt `default` feature user can prevent so , i want to use jAlert, as suggested by my manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [issue#5](https://github.com/VersatilityWerks/jAlert/issues/5):

```
$.fn.jAlert.defaults.confirmQuestion = 'Do you want to add this?';

confirm(
  function(e, btn){ //onConfirm
    e.preventDefault();
    //do something here
    btn.parents('.jAlert').closeAlert();
    return false;
  }, function(e,btn){ //onDeny
    e.preventDefault();
    //do something here
    btn.parents('.jAlert').closeAlert();
    return false;
  }
);
```

or

```
  $.jAlert({
    'type': 'confirm',
    'confirmQuestion': 'Do you want to add this?',
    'onConfirm': function(e, btn){
      e.preventDefault();
      //do something here
      btn.parents('.jAlert').closeAlert();
      return false;
    },
    'onDeny': function(e, btn){
      e.preventDefault();
      //do something here
      btn.parents('.jAlert').closeAlert();
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Created this small [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andreasvirkus/p7n9xdu4/) to replicate a confirm modal/prompt. Hope this helps!

**Edit:** If you're not forced to use jAlert, may I also suggest SweetAlert,
which has a simpler interface/initialisation (and a prettier UI imo). It's also served over a CDN

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Now it's available under a global `swal` variable

A simple confirm prompt would look like this:

```
swal("Are you sure you want to do this?", {
  buttons: ["Oh noez!", "Aww yiss!"],
});
```

See it in action [here](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#advanced-examples)